# How to open & view several images at once?

Tags: windows-7, images, windows-explorer

I have several small images I would like to display all opened at the same time (on my second monitor)?

I would like to multiselect the files in file explorer or from within the tool and get them displayed next to each other.

Any ideas? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to tile the group?

Comment: @soandos What group? I don't want to open each file one at a time.

Comment: So select all of them and hit enter

Answer (score 1):

Without any external tools (there are plenty but maybe not worth installing, depends on you), you could use windows explorer with its "extra-large icons" view options (from the view menu).

To process those files in a separate window/monitor, you can

- Copy the images from their original location
- Open a new Explorer window in a temp directory, displayed as "extra-large icons"
- Right-click > Paste shortcuts in this directory
- work with the shortcuts in the temp directory
- When done, do the merge by hand

If you need a more complex tool, there are plenty that you can download a demo from

Answer (score 1):

I use PhotoFiltre when I need to open several images at the same time: http://www.photofiltre-studio.com/pf7-en.htm

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

1. Right click on an empty part of the task bar
2. Select one of the following options:

   - show windows side by side (auto-arrange windows vertically)
   - show stacked(auto-arrange windows horizontally)
   - cascade

Comment: What program group?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich, my bad, see edit

Comment: This will do it for all opened apps. Not what I want.